# Different xaml on desktop devices and phones

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

Is there any ways use different xaml element properties for different devices? For example I want apply different margins on desktop devices and mobile phones. Maybe there is another way to solve this problem?

Comment: which kind of element? If you use DataTemplatee selector, selector can obtain device and it can select right element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this:

**Visual State Manager**

You can you use it for smaller changes in your XAML based for example on different resolution:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ResponsiveLayout">
            <VisualState x:Name="NarrowLayout">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="MyGrid.Margin" Value="5" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="WideLayout">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1024" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="MyGrid.Margin" Value="15" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

**Differrent XAMLs**

Use it for completly different layout for different devices, also more possibilities to do this:

1. Create folder with name **DeviceFamily-[concreteDevice]** for different device family and make new **XAML View** (just view, if you want to keep code-behind the same for all devices, if you want also different code-behind, use **Blank Page** - same for next possibility) for all pages you want to make different (good choice for many pages):
   [image: Example]
2. Create just new **XAML View** with exact suffix for different device family in your solution, maybe easier for just one or two modified pages, for example:
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

You should look to [VisualStateManager class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.visualstatemanager.aspx%20VisualStateManager%20class).

You can also look at [this blog post for](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/09/01/make-your-app-look-great-on-any-size-screen-or-window-10-by-10/) more information about how to make your XAML-based applications responsive.

> Using the built-in AdaptiveTrigger as the VisualState’s StateTrigger
>   with a MinWindowHeight and/or MinWindowWidth property, visual states
>   can change based on app window height/width.